# Mostrar consola con jquery

Tags: jquery

Como hago para que al presionar un botón en mi página web(dicho botón lo he creado yo) se abra la consola del navegador (usando jquery)?
Ya que debo enviar datos a la consola y quiero que el usuario al presionar el botón pueda ver la consola del navegador y los datos que ahí se almacenan, en vez que presione F12 o se dirija por medio del menú del navegador a la consola

Comment: Nelson, bienvenido a SOes. Porfavor, has el [tour]. Considera [edit] tu pregunta y agregar un [mcve], de lo contrario, tu pregunta sera puesta en espera o cerrada.

Answer (score 1):

He provado lo siguiente que debería funcionar, pero por motivos de seguridad no está permitido. Así que no puedes, al menos de forma sencilla y se me ocurre que tal vez sería mejor, mostrar un DIV con un formato adecuado e ir añadiendo ahí los mensajes que quieras a modo de consola. Este es el intento fallido:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Abrir consola</button>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var csk = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvents');
                csk.initKeyboardEvent(
                    'keydown',
                    true,
                    true,
                    document.defaultView,
                    true, // ctrl
                    false, // alt
                    true, //shift
                    false, //meta key
                    107, // keycode
                    0
                );

                $("button").on("click", function() {
                    $(this).dispatchEvent(csk);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Per como te comento, está desactivado por seguridad mostrando el siguiente error en la consola del navegador: **NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported**

Como esto depende de cada navegador, puede que en alguno funcione, pero lo dudo, ¿imaginas el daño que podrias hacer presinando teclas en el lado del cliente de forma programática?

Una consola sencilla sería lo siguiente:

```js
$(function() {

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $("#terminal").toggle();
  });

  function terminal(str) {
    $("#terminal").append(str + "<br>");
  }
  
  var i = 5;
  var x = 10;
  
  terminal("Suma: " + parseInt(i + x));
  terminal("Multiplicación: " + parseInt(i * x));
  
});
```

```css
#terminal {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="terminal">Mostrar/Ocultar registro<button>
<div id="terminal"></div>
```

De esta forma, puedes usar terminal("mensaje") a modo de console.log("mensaje"), aunque este ejemplo es muy limitado y por ejemplo, no trabaja con objetos, arrays o eventos. En caso de querer algo más completo, te sugiero buscar una consola ya hecha y añadir las funcionalidades que desees como: https://github.com/customd/jquery-console que trabaja con objetos y arrays.

El div del terminal lo puedes poner fixed en la parte de abajo de tu web y se comportará realmente como la consola de las herramientas de desarrollo.